# Using Field Calculator to auto-increment in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table, python-parser

I am trying to edit the basic sequential numbers in a field script using Python in the Field Calculator.

I set the Parser to Python, and for my Pre-logic Script:

```
rec=0
name="manhole"
def autoIncrement(): 
 global rec 
 pStart = 1  
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0):  
  rec = pStart  
 else:  
  rec += pInterval  
 return name, rec
```

And for the box below:

```
autoIncrement()
```

Would this not be how to go about this?

Essentially I just want "manhole1" then "manhole2" then "manhole3", etc.

Comment: That code will put sequential numbers in the fields. If you want to add manhole to it, and it is a string field, just field calculate "manhole" + "numberfield"

Comment: 'Manhole %s' %autoincrement() is one of solutions. Remove name from script.

Answer (score 2):

A field calculator expression using pre-logic code should have a function called that, in the end, returns a single value each time the function is called.  Currently, you are returning two separate values.  To return a single value, you should be able to take your code above and change the line from `return name, rec` to `return 'name' + str(rec)`